# How to use IIB override command with comma separated value

Tags: websphere, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

I'm trying to use IIB override command with kafka node to override the bootstrap value list but the result of this command is always the first value of the list only.
I'm using the command as below:

```
mqsiapplybaroverride -b test1.bar -k "kafkaApp" -m "KafkaConsumer#bootstrapServers=x,y,z"
```

and the result from this command is always as below:

```
<ConfigurableProperty override="x" uri="KafkaConsumer#bootstrapServers"/>
```

It is taking the first value only of the list which is "x" here and truncating the rest of list after the comma.
Could anyone please let me know how to execute the command so that it takes the whole bootstrap list not only the first value ?

Comment: which OS are you using? Linux or Windows?

Comment: It is Windows OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-m` flag does not work if the property value has a comma in it.

Write your overrides into a file and use the `-p` flag:

```
# File: test1.overrides
KafkaConsumer#bootstrapServers=x,y,z
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
mqsiapplybaroverride -b test1.bar -k kafkaApp -p test1.overrides
```